# tossing a coin several times - how many random experiments?

Tags: probability

When you toss a coin, say, 2 times, are there two or one random experiment?
If you think of the sample space as {TT, TF, FT, FF} there is a single random experiment. But I think you can also think of it as two random experiments. Can we use both approaches? Why and why not?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: Are you going to perform two statistical analyses (one for each flip) or one analysis (for the two flips)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you couldn't treat a "double coin flip" as a single experiment with four possible outcomes. It's all a matter of what you're trying to achieve with your model. If you want to model an arbitrarily long sequence of flips, it's best to model it at the atomic level of individual coin flips, since you can add or subtract them as you need. A sequence 9 coin flips, for example, could not be modeled by your double coin flip method.